# How do I prevent an npm module from loading its own style?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, jsx, semantic-ui-react

I'm using Semantic UI React and Semantic UI CSS for a project I'm building with React. I tried to use this npm package called [react-annotation-tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-annotation-tool).

The problem is, that module has bootstrap and reactstrap in its list of dependencies. As soon as I import that module in my component.js file, the entire styling of my app is being changed to that of Bootstrap's. How can I override this behaviour?

Comment: As react does not encapsulate styling so you should wrap your own styles in a kind of namespace. Like `.RSL  .class{}`.

Comment: @Jai My own styles are on top of Semantic UI CSS's styles. But bootstrap is replacing all of Semantic UI CSS's styles and the entire app's styles are messed up even though my own CSS styles are retained.

Comment: Change the package.json file in the dependencies section